# jekyll - pagination not working

Tags: jekyll

I'm working with jekyll but the pagination not working, I thing that I'm doing all ok from official page.

**_config.yml**
paginate: 3

**Gemfile**
gem 'jekyll-paginate'

Index.html

```
{% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %} FUNCIONA!!! 
            {% else %} NOT WORKING {% else %}
            {% endif %}

    {% for post in paginator.posts  %}
            hello3
            {% endfor %}

            {% for post in site.posts  %}
            hello1
            {% endfor %}
```

The posts are .md, is a problem?

Comment: This is supposed to work. Can you provide a repository url ? This can help to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In `_config.yaml` replace the existing single line `paginate` declaration with these three lines:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
paginate: 3
paginate_path: "page:num"
```